# how do you make radio like button in a loop

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js

[image]

i want to make a button that is functioning like radio button

what it is called?
also how you put radio button on a loop like the picture above?

the button input must be wrapped with the div right? but how do you do it

to put it simply, my code goes like this

```
<tr v-for="(material, index) in getmaterials" :key="index">
                      <td>{{ index+1 }}</td>
                      <td>{{ material.product_name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ material.qty }}</td>
                      <td>{{ material.price }}</td>
                      <td>{{ material.budget}}</td>
                      <td><input type="radio" name="radio_a"></td>
                      <td><input type="radio" name="radio_b"></td>
                      <td><input type="radio" name="radio_c"></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only select one radio button in a group of radio buttons with the same name within a form. So your radio buttons on each row would have the same name.

**ex:**

```
<td>
   <input type="radio" id="id_{{ index+1 }}" name="name_{{ index+1 }}" value="value" checked>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want radio inputs then place them directly in your TD elements and give them a name so that they belong to the same group: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

```
<td><input type="radio" id="id" name="name" value="value" checked></td>
```

If you want normal buttons to behave like radio inputs, try wrapping the input in a label, style the label to look like a button, and hide the input.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but the radio button can be selected multiple times within an index? what i want to do is, you can only select 1 within an index from array of object

Comment: If I understand correctly then you need to give all the inputs the same name so they are part of the same group, then only one at a time can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr v-for="(material, index) in getmaterials" :key="index">
              <td>{{ index+1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ material.product_name }}</td>
              <td>{{ material.qty }}</td>
              <td>{{ material.price }}</td>
              <td>{{ material.budget}}</td>
              <td> A <input type="button">radio button </input> </td>
              <td> B <input type="button">radio button </input> </td>
```